# monerod in regtest mode does not remember the generated blockchain

Tags: monerod, regtest

I wanted to try `generateblocks` in regtest mode. It works, blocks get generated. Using the RPC call `get_last_block_header` I can see new blocks and their heights.

Problem is that after monerod restarts, all blocks get lost. It shows initial block at height 0, nothing else. It happens even if I enter `save` and `exit` commands manually, instead of traditional ^D.
I'm using the latest version, v0.17.3.0 on Ubuntu.
I ran monerod with `log-level 3` but didn't find any errors.
It happens to the blocks generated by the traditional way (`start_mining`) as well.

I tried to start a new blockchain in testnet mode and all works correctly (blocks get saved).

What am I doing wrong? Or, what's wrong with regtest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the parameter `--keep-fakechain` if you want to keep a regtest blockchain.